# Creating ad for someone else's page using the Marketing API

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I'm trying to create an ad for someone else's page using the Marketing API.

So far I have

- My own access token which works fine for creating and managing ads for my own page
- Another user's access token with pages_manage_ads and ads_management permissions given for one of their pages

The rest is very confusing. pages_manage_ads is supposedly for creating and managing ads for a page, but the documentation only mentions reading page ads, not creating or editing.

Has anyone gotten this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I've done it before, but some time ago and it often changes in detail. What I would do is going to [API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and try to get to the first success by first reading the ads related to the Page and then creating them by leveraging existing posts there. You can create them in a paused state.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/adgroup

Facebook is all about experimenting, so if you don't want to experiment with your user's page you can create your own dummy page and try it there first.